# How to make jQuery tabs() 100% high and content scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a JS web app with tabs. The speciality of the interface is that the tabs should be as high as the window is and the content should be scrolled if higher than the window. The content is built up from several left floated panels that fill the screen.

I already have part of the solution working but I cannot figure out how to set the *100% height and the scrolling for the container*.

http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/1242/

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="floated"></div>
        <div class="floated"></div>
        <div class="floated"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: jQuery tabs with scrolled content]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/1245/

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.tabs {
height: 100%;
```

}

```
#tab1 {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need `ul{position: fixed;}` to prevent the nav bar disappearing.

Comment: One more issue: the bottom of the content is not visible in this way. The 100% height takes the height of the page but does not consider the tab bar height!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have solved this already, but here is a solution with position: absolute, that works for us.  Could be a starting point for you.
/Staffan

```
    .tabs{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}


.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0px;
height: 18px;
right: 0;
}


.ui-tabs-panel {
position: absolute;
top: 18px;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I already solved this issue but it is definitely good to have several options. Can you add a JSFiddler link?

Answer (score 1):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/1246/).

Keep the UI tabs fixed by using CSS `position:fixed`.

```css
.ui-tabs-nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then use jQuery to give the contents a `margin-top` so that they would be shown below the UI tabs by default.

```javascript
$("#tab1").css("margin-top", $(".ui-tabs-nav").height());
```

Comment: Thank you. This kin of works but the content goes behind the tab bar and looks weird. Also, the scroll bar is overlapping the tab bar.